# If $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $f^{-1}$ is a function, then f is 1-1.

Tags: functions, multivalued-functions

Just verifying if this proof is valid.

Claim: If $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $f^{-1}$ is  a function, then $f$ is $1-1$.

Proof: Suppose $f(a)=f(z)$ where $a,z\in A$.

This implies that $(a,b)\in f$ and $(z,b)\in f$, where $b\in B$

Which then implies that $(b,a)\in f^{-1}$ and $(b,z)\in f^{-1}$

Since $f^{-1}$ is a function, $a=z$

So, $f(a)=f(b) \implies a=z$

Therefore $f$ is $1-1$

Comment: What does "$f^{-1}$ is a function" mean?

Comment: I'm not the OP, but it sounds like it means that the preimage of a point is a point.

Comment: I think what he means is that $f$ has an inverse.

Comment: @zhw My guess would be that in ZFC, $f$ is literally identified with a subset of $A \times B$ which in turn gives a relation between $A$ and $B$ (in more type-based systems it would be the relation $\lambda (x:A) (y:B) . (f(x) = y)$).  So, it has an inverse relation between $B$ and $A$, and you ask if that inverse relation "is" (type-theoretically, "comes from") a function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a lot of the elements of a proper proof are there; however, your chain of reasoning is completely in the wrong order.  In particular, just showing $\exists a\in A, \exists z\in A, f(a) = f(z) \wedge a = z$ is definitely *not* sufficient to show $f$ is one-to-one.  What you need to show is: $\forall a\in A, \forall z \in A, f(a) = f(z) \rightarrow a = z$.

Comment: I don't agree at beginning he choose arbitrary $a,z$ which translates to for every $a,z$

Comment: @kingW3 Still, about the closest thing I could see this proving would be $\forall b\in B, \forall a\in A, \forall z \in A, (b, a) \in f^{-1} \wedge (b, z) \in f^{-1} \rightarrow f(a) = f(z) \wedge a = z$, from which isn't not at all clear you can conclude $f$ is one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

*Daniel is right. Is not sufficient your proof.

Have good arguments but I think you can do better.

Take a look at this proof:*

Let $a, b \in A$ and $f(a)=f(b)$.
Since,  $f^{-1}$ is a function and $f(a), f(b) \in B$ with $f(a)=f(b)$,
we have that $f^{-1}(f(a))=f^{1}(f(b)) \rightarrow a=b$

*Notice that I chose to prove 1-1 using: If $f(a)=f(b) \rightarrow a=b$.

You can also prove if the negation of this: If $a\neq b \rightarrow f(a) \neq f(b)$*

Comment: Is this a better proof? I'm sorry I responded late.

Comment: I think so @JamesSnell